# My style sheet is suddenly not working

Tags: html, css

I scratched up a log in page the other day for a small project I'm working on. I did barely any of it, bar making the background and the navbar. When I continued working on it, any changes I made to CSS did not work. Example being when I tried to color of the H1s to white. I have tried clearing my cache for Mozilla in case something got corrupted but no hope.

Also, weirdly I think I'm getting that whole "user agent style sheet" problem(noticed when opened on chrome). Any suggestions?

Heres the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title> BitStudy </title>  
<script src="man.js"></script> 
<link rel=styleSheet HREF="home.css" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">BitStudy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#about">Log in</a></li>
</ul>


<h1>Testing</h1>
  
    
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```css
body,html{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/back1.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:80%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #ff751a;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}

h1{color:white;}
```

Comment: "user agent style sheet" is not an error. It is how the browser renders the page by default

Comment: In your network panel (developer tools of the browser), is `home.css` being loaded?

Comment: It has been loaded!

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/w93sh7aL/ - It must be something with your set-up. In the response tab of the network panel, can you see the CSS and is it the valid CSS? Do you have other CSS overwriting `home.css`?

Answer (score 0):

First: ensure that the index.html and home.css are in the same folder.
Then change HREF to href as Mandar Sant said.
Finally add double string quote to the stylesheet as in rel="stylesheet". so that you have somthing like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" type="text/css" >
```

Instead of the code below y had initially.

```
<link rel=styleSheet HREF="home.css" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: I did all those things and still no luck! Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Can you put fiddle of your code here so we can see with you.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on local and all looks fine, make sure you have the right permissions on the .css file, in that case check on the NET tab in developer tools (F12) if the file is correctly included.